# Download a web page using wget and define a new filename

Tags: bash, wget

I need to write a script in bash using `wget` which download a web page which has been passed to an argument and then the script should put the extracted page in a new *file.html* and then also extract all the tags of the web page in a second file  and keep only the content of the web page.

This is the beginning of my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
$page = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_web"
wget -r  -np '$page' file.html
```

From the second part, I am blocked.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
page="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_web"
wget -O file.html -r -np "$page"
```

1. Variable assignment: `var_name=value` (no space allowed around `=`)
2. Bash is not PHP, `$var=val` is not correct, `var=val` is.
3. Use double quote to allow variable expansion (`"$page"`)

From `wget` manual:

> ```
> -O file
>
>   --output-document=file
>
>        The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
>        will be concatenated together and written to file.
> ```

Comment: Hello! i tried your command but it does not work!  the script created the new file but there is nothing inside.

Comment: @EMMAKENJI : There's error in your first part too, I didn't notice that, updated...